Prayer in tight clothes
My question is related to women clothing in prayer.If prayer in tight clothes is haram than how is the prayer not invalid?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].
